Consulta MySql en Prestashop para obtener pedidos agrupados por países
soy nueva por aquí así que, ante todo, disculpad si no planteo correctamente el problema.
Necesito una consulta SQL para prestashop que me devuelva

ps_country.id_country
ps_country_lang.name
sumatorio de ps_orders.total_paid_tax_incl
sumatorio de ps_orders.total_paid_tax_excl.

Condiciones a cumplir:

ps_orders.valid igual a 1,
ps_orders.invoice_date BETWEEN '2024-01-01' AND '2024-01-31'.

El código que tengo es el siguiente, pero no me arroja resultados. No se si me hace falta incluir algún join más o hay otras cosas mal en el planteamiento,  pero por muchas vueltas que le de no consigo que me devuelva los registros correctos.
Muchas gracias.
SELECT 
    c.id_country,
    cl.name,
    SUM(oi.total_paid_tax_incl) AS total_paid_tax_incl_sum,
    SUM(oi.total_paid_tax_excl) AS total_paid_tax_excl_sum
FROM 
    ps_country c
INNER JOIN 
    ps_country_lang cl ON c.id_country = cl.id_country
LEFT JOIN 
    ps_orders o ON o.id_address_delivery = c.id_country
LEFT JOIN 
    ps_order_invoice oi ON oi.id_order = o.id_order
WHERE 
    o.valid = 1
    AND o.invoice_date BETWEEN '2024-01-01' AND '2024-01-31'
GROUP BY 
    c.id_country, cl.name


Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla! sin ver la db, no podemos hacer mucho.. esa query parece estar correcta, no hay mucho que probar... salvo que el campo de fechas este mal, todo el resto no parece tener problema...

Sin conocer demasiado el prestahop y sin poder probarlo, diria que confundes el id_address_delivery con el id_country.  Diria que necesitas mas bien equiparar el ps_orders.id_address_delivery con el ps_adress.id_address y de ahi sacar el id_country correspondiente.

Estás relacionando la tabla orders directamente con la tabla de países (country), pero la tabla de órdenes no tiene relación directa con la tabla de países.
Puedes relacionarla, por ejemplo, a través de la tabla de direcciones (address).
En general, por lo que pude ver al consultar la documentación de la estructura de la base de datos de prestashop, esta mantiene consistencia en el nombre de los campos, por lo que esta condición del join:
o.id_address_delivery = c.id_country
Debería causarte mucho ruido, pues los nombres de los campos que estás comparando no coinciden en nada, y es de esperar que tengan nombres similares (más prefijos y sufijos).
Por otro lado, encuentro otros errores en tu consulta:

El enunciado indica que extraigas la sumatoria de ps_orders.total_paid_tax_incl, pero tú estás extrayendo el valor de la tabla ps_order_invoice.
Esto lleva a que incluyes a la tabla de facturas (invoice), pero en realidad  no debes extraer ningún dato de ella ni es necesaria para relacionar otras tablas, por lo que no debiera aparecer en la cláusula from.

Finalmente, ya que vamos a resumir órdenes, yo partiría de esa tabla en la cláusula from para ir armando las relaciones necesarias hasta llegar a las tablas necesarias para extraer los datos. En mi opinión, ir en la vía contraria resulta confuso.
Por lo tanto, yo tendría algo como:
select   c.id_country
       , cl.name
       , sum(o.total_paid_tax_incl) sum_total_paid_tax_incl
       , sum(o.total_paid_tax_excl) sum_total_paid_tax_excl
  from ps_orders o
       inner join ps_address ad on ad.id_address = o.id_address_delivery
       inner join ps_country c on c.id_country = ad.id_country
       inner join ps_country_lang cl on cl.id_country = c.id_country
 where o.valid = 1
   and o.invoce_date between '2024-01-01' AND '2024-01-31'
 group by c.id_country, cl.name

Hasta aquí, puedo comentar que si la base de datos tiene varios registros en la tabla de lenguajes, existe la posibilidad de que los países se repitan con los nombres en los distintos lenguajes que tengan configurados en los resultados.
Es decir, la consulta va a funcionar bien en un sistema mono-lenguaje, pero va a fallar en uno multilingue. Desconozco prestashop, por lo que no podría decir qué hacer exactamente para resolver este tema. Eso queda como ejercicio para el lector.

Tienes LEFT [OUTER] JOIN ps_orders o, pero también tienes:
WHERE o.valid = 1
AND o.invoice_date BETWEEN '2024-01-01' AND '2024-01-31'

En una outer-join fila los campos son NULL. Entonces estas convertiendo tu outer join a un inner join.
Tu consulta corregida:
SELECT 
    c.id_country,
    cl.name,
    SUM(oi.total_paid_tax_incl) AS total_paid_tax_incl_sum,
    SUM(oi.total_paid_tax_excl) AS total_paid_tax_excl_sum
FROM 
    ps_country c
INNER JOIN 
    ps_country_lang cl ON c.id_country = cl.id_country
LEFT JOIN 
    ps_orders o ON o.id_address_delivery = c.id_country
                AND o.valid = 1
                AND o.invoice_date BETWEEN DATE '2024-01-01' AND DATE '2024-01-31'
LEFT JOIN 
    ps_order_invoice oi ON oi.id_order = o.id_order
GROUP BY 
    c.id_country, cl.name
ORDER BY 
    c.id_country, cl.name;

Este parte se ve raro:
ON o.id_address_delivery = c.id_country

Un address (dirección) y un country (país) son dos cosas diferentes. Quizás id_address_delivery solamente es un mal nombre y debe ser id_country. O quizás tienes un error aquí en tu consulta.
